# Plot linear equation using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an equation using matplotlib. If I input some dummy data:

```
from numpy import arange
i = arange(0.0, 50.0)
```

And insert the equation as the following:

```
y4 = .00001              
y3 = .00002            
y2 = .00003               
y1 = .00004              
y0 = .00005

x = y4 * math.pow(i, 4) + y3 * math.pow(i, 3) + y2 * math.pow(i, 2) + y1 * i + y0
```

It returns an error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got `numpy` imported, it's easier to use `np.power` instead of `math.pow`, as it works with arrays, or even just the `**` operator:

```
x = y4 * np.power(i, 4) + y3 * np.power(i, 3) + y2 * np.power(i, 2) + y1 * i + y0

plt.plot(i,x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This may have to be another question. But If I wanted to include an if x > 30: x = 30. Would that have to be included in the equation or could it be called as a separate function?

Comment: You could use `np.clip`: `x = np.clip(x, a_min = None, a_max=(30))`

Comment: Brilliant. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You should be using numpy when working with numpy arrays.

```
x = y4 * i**4 + y3 * i**3 + y2 * i**2 + y1 * i + y0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want use numpy then `import numpy as np` if you want to use math then `import math`.